# PCB challenges and breadboard feasibility

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, breadboard

I'm building a system that contains several chips (Intel 8085, 4 shift registers, SRAM, 8255 I/O) all connected to a common address and data bus. The highest frequency signals in the circuit are on the 8 MHz SPI bus used by the PIC18 monitor to shift bits (address or data) into and out of the SIPO and PISO registers. The frequency is that high because I want to capture all 8085 bus activity if possible. The next frequency is the 500 kHz (at most) parallel A/D bus.

[image: schematic]

I just began component placing and routing in Eagle and I've found the task daunting. So challenging that I'm considering scrapping the PCB and completing the entire circuit on a large breadboard, especially considering the fact that the only PCB I've ever designed is a 6x4 keypad in KiCAD which is nothing compared to a system of this complexity. I can't afford to spend a week patiently designing, wait weeks for the board to arrive, solder costly components only to have the board not work. I know mentioning deadlines here isn't cool but I *do* have a deadline in 3 weeks.

I've asked a question related to this issue [before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254739/parallel-buses-on-a-breadboard) and Chris Stratton said that crosstalk is an issue mostly in theory (also use short wires, bypass, etc) but what I'm looking for some confirmation ("Yes its very doable though...") or a definite no-no ("You can't do it. Go play with something else."). Specifically,

- Has anyone else here designed something similar **on a breadboard** and it worked without glitches? No tricks to it but keep the wires as short as possible and bypass power on every rail?
- What are the odds that someone inexperienced in PCB design could design such a circuit well enough for it to work perfectly the first time after fabrication (at some fab house)? That is, barring any issues with code.

I would test this myself with a breadboard but I'm just about to order the final components needed for breadboard testing or those needed for the final PCB (IC sockets and the like). Which ones I purchase depend on the answers I get from you guys.

Comment: 8MHz on breadboard may be an issue. The stray capacitance on breadboards is huge and will likely kill your signals having tried it before.

Comment: Even someone inexperienced can do a lot to make sure a PCB design works by double/triple/quadruple checking all the schematic, and checking the ERC in Eagle to look for unconnected pins etc.

Comment: @TomCarpenter There are only 3 wires that will carry 8 MHz signals (MOSI, MISO, SCK). Keeping the wires as short as possible wont do any good with the stray capacitance? I let the AutoRouter loose before on the PCB and the results weren't pretty. Now I'm doing it myself beginning with high-freq lines but the ratsnest isnt encouraging. My main issue though is with all the arcana of PCB design: distance btw certain types of signals, trace widths, clearances etc. I'm certain I'll miss something.

Comment: You will likely have better luck wire wrapping a board together.  Also, complex designs are difficult to create with out errors or faults when using bread boards.

Comment: Some will frown at me for this, but I use eagle as well to make complex circuits like yours shown and I let the auto-router do the work. If it can't complete the job, then I add staples as wire (one at a time) to my schematic until the auto-router routes my board at 100%. If you really lack patience, then you can use a very coarse grid setting in the auto-router (like 1mm+ grid) but you won't get good results. And do you really need 8Mhz?

Comment: @Mike I need 8 MHz to capture addresses as they are placed on the bus by the 8085. Frequency needs to be that high since I still have to shift whatever I capture through the 16-bit register into my PIC. The autorouter *did* complete the routing (even when I set effort to High) but the problem is it will route all signals with the same priority, high frequency or not. So I may end up with an SCLK line that's also an antenna and editing the routed PCB would be about impossible. What do you mean by 'staples'?

Comment: staples as in use a stapler in mid air and let a staple out and connect it to the board and it will act as a wire.

Comment: Yes I've done something of this complexity by breadboarding, but don't expect it to go any faster than the PCB process. First rule of PCB layout is placement, placement. placement. Experiment with component placement until the ratsnests are as short and simple as possible. Spend a day doing just that. Or playing http://planarity.net/ until you get the hang of it. Then route by hand; autorouters (especially on cheap/free tools) are a mess. And don't expect the first pass of the PCB to work perfectly either - that's what scalpels, Dremels and tack wire are for.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. From what you say, it takes patience to produce a working PCB of this complexity (as it should) but I have little time left (actually doing all this between exams). But you've built something similar on a breadboard. Is there any reason why I shouldnt continue with that option? Why wont it be faster thab the PCB process?

Comment: Nobody has ever designed anything on any breadboard without glitches. I wouldn't even recommend them for hobbyists or students. Get some through-hole parts and solder them on a PCB if you want something that is stable and useful. A cheap, basic solder iron probably cost about as much as the breadboard junk. Also did I read it correctly, you are _designing_ something new based on Intel 8085? If so, then there's probably no hope for this project, breadboard or not.

Comment: @Lundin I understand what you mean. A PCB would definitely be more reliable and professional besides but it requires significant investment in time and money, especially for someone who hasnt done any real PCB work before and finds himself with a deadline. I *do* intend to try and design the PCB, but till it arrives and works, I have to continue with the breadboard so I have something tangible; no sense in putting so many eggs in one basket. What I'm designing isnt new, except maybe for the part where a PIC monitors the 8085. Why is there no hope?

Comment: @TisteAndii Regarding the PCB: some misc lab PCB, a cheap soldering iron and some misc through-hole passives are hardly expensive. Even if you can't solder well, the quality will still be lightyears ahead of some breadboard rat's nest. Regarding the MCU: ...because it is a MCU from the mid-70s that most likely has been discontinued for the past 20 years or so?

Comment: @Lundin Neither purchasing soldering tools nor the actual soldering is a problem. Cost of PCB fabrication + wasted soldered components are some of the main issues. But even more than that, is the problem of waiting. A board that doesn't work (a very real possibility for a beginner) will mean time spent in debugging, re-designing and most of all, waiting for weeks for the board (and new components) to arrive from China. I've seen a number of 8085 SBCs online, the age of the chip shouldn't be a problem, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone's interested, I finally built a part of the circuit (PIC + 8 MHz SPI + registers + SRAM) on a breadboard and it worked on first try; the PIC was programmed to write to the first 512 RAM addresses, read from those same addresses and print to the serial port for me to verify.

I use shielded twisted pair wire (taking advantage of the different colours) and I made sure to keep the wires short, especially the SPI lines. I included bypass caps on the rails, though I noticed the circuit still worked even when I removed the caps. In any case, I'm scrapping the design since I just belatedly realized that I have 33 I/O pins on the PIC and the registers are not only unnecessary but make the circuit difficult to build, route and also contribute to load the parallel bus. PCB routing should now be less painful hopefully.